# $wpdb select returns empty array

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to query databse to get posts with `meta_key` equals `meta_value` but it returns empty array, while if i used `get_posts` i got required result, what is wrong with my code (I hooked it to footer to check)

```
global $wpdb;


$wpdb->show_errors( true );
$querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'workshop_id'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '13465'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'forum'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.ID ASC
";


$workshops = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

print_r($workshops);
```

Using this:

```
$workshops = get_posts([
    'post_type'   => 'forum',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'    => 'workshop_id',
    'meta_value'  =>  '13465',
]);

print_r($workshops);
```

i get:

```
 Array
 (
[0] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 13562
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2019-01-02 20:05:21
        [post_date_gmt] => 2019-01-02 17:05:21
        //And the rest of properties..
    )
 )
```

> **Update**

I have tried the following query and it worked(Why the one with problem doesn't):

```
$workshops_query = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
        SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta
         WHERE meta_key = %s
         AND meta_value = %s
        ",
            'workshop_id', '13465'
        )
, OBJECT);
foreach($workshops_query as $workshop_query){
    $workshops[] = $workshop_query->post_id;
}
```

And yes both of queries tends to return different results, but one of them works, why the other doesn't?

Comment: And do you get any errors from WPDB?

Comment: no errors, i also tried to add `$wpdb->show_errors( true )` before query string but nothing changes.

Comment: And are you 100% sure that this query is correct? I can't see anything wrong from PHP/SQL point of view and if I change it to some other conditions (published posts with some meta existing on my site), then it works correctly. So maybe there is something wrong with your conditions.

Comment: I have made an update to question please check it out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just use `get_posts()`? It's best practice to use WP's built-in functions where possible.

Comment: yes but i am trying to do this because i have created an event which should fetch posts and do stuff but for some reason get_post dosn't work insid the callback function of event hook so i thought their might be a problem i don't know so i thought database query might help but turns out it doesn't work also but the point here why i can't get results if the query is correct